# Transforming a DAG-like resolution proof to a tree like resolution proof

Tags: sat, proof-complexity

How can a DAG-like resolution proof be transformed to a tree-like resolution proof?

Is such a transformation possible in polynomial time?

Comment: It's an exercise to come up with a transformation with exponential blow up, and that's sometimes necessary: http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/BIW03/biw03.pdf. Moreover, the paper shows a more efficient transformation than the trivial one.

Comment: Thanks. the paper is a bit long. I'll read it carefully to see how the authors proceed.